# How to define an inner method whose name finish with a question mark and that has access to the outer method variables?

Tags: ruby

Here is the target specification:

- the method ends with `?`
- the method can reach the outer block variables, without relying on class attribute shared scope.

Actually I did find a way to respond to this specification:

```
  def resource
    user = try_fetch_current_user
    define_singleton_method(:access_anyway?) do user&.admin? || false end
    @display = OpenStruct.new(
      'resource1?': user&.role1? || access_anyway?,
      'resource2?': user&.role2? || access_anyway?
    )
  end
```

Note: Here `define_singleton_method` was chose over `define_method` as the latter was not defined in the context of use.

So that does the trick, but is rather ugly and doesn't highlight well, compared to :

```
  def resource
    @user = try_fetch_current_user
    def access_anyway? do @user&.admin? || false end
    @display = OpenStruct.new(
      'resource1?': @user&.role1? || access_anyway?,
      'resource2?': @user&.role2? || access_anyway?
    )
  end
```

or even

```
  def resource
    user = try_fetch_current_user
    access_anyway = user&.admin? || false
    @display = OpenStruct.new(
      'resource1?': user&.role1? || access_anyway,
      'resource2?': user&.role2? || access_anyway
    )
  end
```

and lastly:

```
  def resource
    def access_anyway? do try_fetch_current_user&.admin? || false end
    user = try_fetch_current_user
    @display = OpenStruct.new(
      'resource1?': user&.role1? || access_anyway?,
      'resource2?': user&.role2? || access_anyway?
    )
  end
```

With the second solution, @user will unnecessarily leak into the view (when used as a RoR controller method). With the third solution, which is far more clean in my opinion, the question mark is lost which makes the intention far less clear at a first glance. And the last one is less cluttered than the first, but not as clean as the third, and will possibly duplicate heavy operations with a second call to `try_fetch_current_user`.

So, is there a way to express things as cleanly as the third solution, while keeping the question mark, and without calling the `try_fetch_current_user` twice?

Comment: Ruby doesn’t have inner methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to define an inner method whose name finish with a question mark and that has access to the outer method variables?

Ruby doesn't have inner methods, so you cannot define one.

Comment: Maybe I'm out of the custom terminology. In any case something seems to be out of my knowledge: It's clearly possible to run something like `def outer; def inner; p :ô end; inner; end; outer`. So are this methods only syntactically intertwined, but appear on the same hierarchical logical level as far as the scope are concerned?

Comment: This is *not* an "inner method" / "nested method" or whatever it is called in other languages, like e.g. Scala or ECMAScript have them. What you have is simply a method definition that is executed when you call the method. However, a method definition without an explicit definee (e.g. `def foo.bar`) is always defined on the closest lexically enclosing module definition, and since the closest lexically enclosing module definition in your case is the same for both method definitions, both `inner` and `outer` will be defined in the same module.

Comment: The `inner` *method* is *not* nested inside the `outer` method. Rather, the `inner` method *definition* is nested inside the `outer` method *body*. This simply means that the `def inner` definition will be executed when you call `outer` (and will, in fact, be executed *every time you call `outer`, giving you a "method overwritten" warning), not that it is somehow "nested" inside the method. And, since there is actually absolutely no relationship whatsoever between the two methods, they also cannot access each other's local variable scopes.